# Can I just add an application.properties file to a Spring Boot project?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, server, spring-data-mongodb

I'm fairly new to Spring Boot and MongoDB. Currently I have a project that can send data back and forth to a server that is running locally on my computer, but I want to change this and make it edit and retrieve data from an externally running database. In other tutorials I have followed I have had an application.properties file that I can edit details in to get it to connect, but I can't find this in any of the sub folders (I pulled the code from a tutorial) and I can't find anything to say that it is specifically connecting to the local instance.
Would it be okay to just create the application.properties file in the right sub folder and enter the external database's details there? Or am I going to have to try a separate method and tutorial to try and connect to the external database in another way?
I have a feeling that to answer it you will need to see/understand more of the code, but I'm not sure how to summarise anything else or what would actually be relevant. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot has several default folders, where it searches for properties.
One of those places is for example *src/main/resources/application.properties*, there you can just create this file.

An overview of other possible places for Spring Boot properties can be found here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

In my German blog I wrote an article about how to use Spring-data to access MongoDB - there I used also application.properties file:
https://agile-coding.blogspot.com/2020/10/keine-ahnung-von-mongodb-dann-nimm.html